# How to interpret weird date/timestamp formats

Tags: date, datetime, time

I have some documents that have a timestamp that I cannot seem to interpret it. The timestamp looks in the following ways:

> 131816723980463000

or

> 1,30989743231727E+32

or

> 130989741742563000

Does anyone know what to use to interpret these date formats? I tried the date time from pandas, most of the date formats from excel, I cannot find anything that resembles somethings that a human can read.

Comment: Looks like a number of microseconds from the epoch. Your example would be in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably LDAP timestamps or Microsoft filetimes. Those are the same.

In that case

- 131816723980463000 would be Monday, September 17, 2018 3:39:58 PM GMT
- 130989741742563000 would be Wednesday, February 3, 2016 11:56:14 AM GMT

The middle one with the exponent is funny, though. Having the first 8 digits in common with the last one my guess is it’s the same only shifted 15 decimal digits to the left and printed in scientific notation.

A Microsoft filetime is a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

**Links**

- [LDAP, Active Directory & Filetime Timestamp Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/ldap)
- [FILETIME structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) in Microsoft documentation

Comment: Thank you for the help! Really appreciated the links too :D